# How to echo data from a bitcoin exchange API showing the latest prices

Tags: php, api

Sorry if this is a bad question but i'm trying to echo the "last" price of bitcoin from the array below and i keep getting the "unidentified index" error.

How would I echo the last price of btc?

{"status":"ok","prices":{"btc":{"bid":"15500","ask":"15600","last":"15600"},"ltc":{"bid":"255.51","ask":"31.434513687425632","last":"274.99"},"doge":{"bid":"0.011001","ask":"0.0112","last":"0.011"}}}

This is my code so far:

```
<?php

$url = "https://www.coinspot.com.au/pubapi/latest"; 

$getContent = file_get_contents($url);   

$json = json_decode($getContent, true);   

echo $json["last"];           

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you are indexing the array wrong. it should be

```
$url = "https://www.coinspot.com.au/pubapi/latest"; 

$getContent = file_get_contents($url);   

$json = json_decode($getContent, true);   

echo $json['prices']['btc']["last"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you see the pretty format of your JSON:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "prices": {
        "btc": {
            "bid": "15500",
            "ask": "15600",
            "last": "15600"
        },
        "ltc": {
            "bid": "255.51",
            "ask": "31.434513687425632",
            "last": "274.99"
        },
        "doge": {
            "bid": "0.011001",
            "ask": "0.0112",
            "last": "0.011"
        }
    }
}
```

You have decoded it into PHP array. If you look carefully or `var_dump` that array then you will see that there `last` key of `btc` in under `price` then `btc` then `last`. So, you need to print like:

`echo $json['prices']['btc']["last"];`